# How to prevent app crash when mongodb primary is down

Tags: mongodb

There is a replica-set, I shutdown the primary node, then access my web site which developed by C++, and it crashes.
Question is how to prevent the crash, just resume the functionality after a new primary is elected.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by crash.

If you mean you cannot write to MongoDB then there is no way around this except to wait the 10 seconds (normally less) it takes to elect a new primary.

As for reading you can make it so that it is primaryPreferred, this way your application is still able to read just not write.

Comment: I just tried, if I shutdown mongodb server using db.shutdownServer(), my app doesn't crash. It crashes when I just shutdown virtual machine before. I will try it again.

Comment: It's wried. I cannot reproduce the crash even if I execute 'halt -p' to shutdown my VM. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: @DeanChen No problem, most likely it might have been something in the app itself